# are acyclic fibrations of nice spaces absolute extensors for perfectly normal spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

A space $Y$ is called an *absolute extensor for normal spaces* (also sometimes *solid*) if, for any normal space $X$, closed subset $A$ of $X$, and map $f:A\to Y$, there exists a map $f′:X\to Y$ such that $f′|A=f$, i.e.
$A\to X$ has the left lifting property with respect to the map $Y\to pt$
from $Y$ to a singleton $pt$
$$A\to B \perp Y\to pt$$

<s>What is the analogous notion for a *map* $g:Y_1\to Y_2$ instead of a space $Y$?</s> The analogous notion for maps instead of spaces is called being *soft with respect to a pair of spaces $(A,B)$* where $A$ is a closed subset of a normal space $B$.  (E. V. Shchepin, Soft maps of manifolds, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 1984, Volume 39, Issue 5(239), 209–224; \S2, Def.).
Are there any references ? Obviously a necessary condition is being a Serre acyclic fibration.

In more details:

> Scchepin [ibid] calls a map $g:Y_1\to Y_2$ *soft with respect to a pair of spaces $X,A$* where $A\subset X$ iff the inclusion map
> $i:A\to X$ has the left lifting property with respect to the map $Y\to pt$
> from $Y$ to a singleton $pt$
> $$A\xrightarrow{i} B \perp Y_1\xrightarrow{g} Y_2$$

What is known about this notion ?

Is a Serre fibration of sufficiently nice spaces (say, a cellular map of finite CW complexes) necessarily soft for any pair $X,A$ where $A$ is a closed subset of hereditary perfectly normal space $X$ ?

A map $p:|Y|\to Y$
from the geometric realisation of a finite simplicial complex
to the simplicial complex viewed as a finite topological space,
does indeed have this property, by the lifting theorem for finite spaces
([Thm. 3.5, Eric Wofsey](https://www.docdroid.net/zJI3nw2/finite-spaces-wofsey-pdf)), see details of the statement [in this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408100/lifting-theorem-for-finite-spaces-replacing-perfect-normality-by-normality).

Comment: There is a notion of _soft map_ by Eugene Schepin , e.g. see E. V. Shchepin, Soft maps of manifolds, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 1984, Volume 39, Issue 5(239), 209–224, or A. Chigogidze, Inverse Spectra, North Holland, Amsterdam, 1996, and reference therein. I haven't yet understood whether they are related to this particular question.

Comment: Let $C\mathbb{N}$ be the cone over a countably infinite discrete complex (this is a contractible 1-dimensional polyhedron). van Douwen and Pol have constructed a countable regular $T_2$ space $X$ (which is thus perfectly normal) and a function $A\rightarrow C\mathbb{N}$, defined on a certain closed $A\subseteq X$, which does not extend over any neighboourhood in $X$. In particular, the map of countable complexes $C\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\ast$ is both a Hurewicz fibration and a homotopy equivalence, but is not soft wrt all perfectly normal pairs.

Comment: On the other hand, if you restrict to (suitably nice) acyclic Serre fibrations between (suitably nice) *finite* complexes, then something should be true. How far you get with this will probably depend on your knowledge of selection theory.

Comment: Many thanks, interesting! Though I was not able to find online their paper, presumably  van Douwen, Eric K.; Pol, Roman Countable spaces without extension properties. Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. 25 (1977), no. 10, 987--991. (Reviewer: D. J. Lutzer) 54C20. Frankly, I do find it rather surprising if the statement isn't known (either proof or some standard counterexample, for finite complexes...)

Comment: Following up the names you gave,  found a maybe useful result in (van Douwen, E. K.; Lutzer, D. J.; Przymusi\'nski, T. C. Some extensions of the Tietze-Urysohn theorem. Amer. Math. Monthly 84 (1977), no. 6, 435--441. (Reviewer: J. Dugundji) 54E40 (54E35)): for A closed in X normal, there is a continuous map $C^{bounded}(A)\to C^{bounded}(X)$ where $C^{bounded}(X)$ denotes the space of bounded continous functions on $X$.. Does this result belong a result to "selection theory" you refer to ?

Comment: The paper *Countable spaces without extension properties* contains the construction of $X$. I couldn't find a copy online, but I'd be grateful if anyone does track down a digital copy.

Comment: The case for finite complexes is probably already known. Every finite complex is a metrisable ANR, and each acyclic Serre fibration between such is a Hurewicz fibration and a homotopy equivalence. Any such map between finite complexes is already soft for the class of (finite-dimensional) paracompacta. The jump from here to perfectly normal spaces should be doable, but I'm afraid that I'm not the person to fill in the gaps.

Comment: thanks! what is a reference for "Any such map between finite complexes is already soft for the class of (finite-dimensional) paracompacta." ?

Comment: See the book *Continuous Selections of Multivalued Mappings* by Repovs and Semenov, and consult Th.5.22 on pg. 291. Given what I've told you in the previous paragraph, the only nontrivial thing to prove is that the family $\{f^{-1}(y)\}$ is ELC$^n$ for any $n$, and this is contained elsewhere in the book.