# are trivial fibrations of finite CW-complexes soft for normal maps?

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Are trivial Hurewicz fibrations of finite CW-complexes soft for normal maps,
i.e. is it true that for any trivial Hurewicz fibration $f:Y_1\to Y_2$
and a closed subset $A$ of a hereditary normal space $B$ the inclusion $i:A\to B$
has the left lifting property  with respect to $Y_1\xrightarrow f Y_2$, i.e.
$$(A\xrightarrow{i} B) \perp (Y_1\xrightarrow{f} Y_2) ?$$

Would this hold for hereditary perfectly normal spaces and/or locally trivial maps ?
Or fibrations of very nice spaces, say coming from smooth maps of compact manifolds ?

This fails for the trivial fibration $C\mathbb{N}\to pt$, [as pointed out by @Tyrone](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408590/are-acyclic-fibrations-of-nice-spaces-absolute-extensors-for-perfectly-normal-sp)

> Let $C\mathbb{N}$ be the cone over a countably infinite discrete complex (this is a contractible 1-dimensional polyhedron).
> van Douwen and Pol [van Douwen, Eric K.; Pol, Roman Countable spaces without extension properties. Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys. 25 (1977), no. 10, 987--991.]  have constructed a countable regular $T_2$ space $X$ (which is thus perfectly normal) and a function $A\to C\mathbb{N}$, defined on a certain closed $A\subseteq X$, which does not extend over any neighboourhood in $X$.
> In particular, the map of countable complexes $C\mathbb{N}\to *$ is both a Hurewicz fibration and a homotopy equivalence,
> but is not soft wrt all perfectly normal pairs. –
> Tyrone Nov 20 at 17:55

and does hold for finite-dimensional paracompacta instead of normal spaces.

> The case for finite complexes is probably already known. Every finite complex is a metrisable ANR, and each acyclic Serre fibration between such is a Hurewicz fibration and a homotopy equivalence. Any such map between finite complexes is already soft for the class of (finite-dimensional) paracompacta. The jump from here to perfectly normal spaces should be doable, but I'm afraid that I'm not the person to fill in the gaps. –
> Tyrone
> 2 days ago
> See the book *Continuous Selections of Multivalued Mappings* by Repovs and Semenov, and consult Th.5.22 on pg. 291. Given what I've told you in the previous paragraph, the only nontrivial thing to prove is that the family $\{f^{−1}(y)\}$
> is $ELC^n$ for any $n$, and this is contained elsewhere in the book. –
> Tyrone 2 days ago

For reader's convenience I quote in full Theorem 5.22:

Theorem (5.22) For a mapping $f:X\to Y$ between metrizable compacta the following assertions are equivalent:
(a) $f$ is an $n$-soft mapping [i.e. for each closed subset $i:A\subset B$ of a paracompact Hausdorff space $B$ with Lebesgue dimension $n$
$$ A\xrightarrow{i} B \perp X\xrightarrow{f} Y$$
(b) $f$ is an open surjection, all fibres $f^{-1}(y)$ are $(n-1)$-connected, and the family $\{f^{-1}(y)\}_{y\in Y}$ is
equi-$(n-1)$-connected.

The terms used are defined as follows.

A space $F$ is *$n$-connected* iff
$$S^m\to B^{m+1} \perp  F \to \{pt\}$$
where $S^m\to B^{m+1}$ is the embedding of the $m$-sphere into the $(m+1)$-ball.

Definition (5.6) A family $L$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is called *equi-$n$-connected* or *in $ELC^n$*
iff for every $A \in L$, every point $x\in A$, and every neighbourhood $W_x\ni x$ of $x$
there is a neighbourhood $x\in V_x\subset W_x $ such that

(i) for every $A'\in L$ intersecting $V_x$, i.e. $V_x\cap A'\neq \emptyset$,
every continuous mapping $S^n\to A'\cap V_x$
is null-homotopic in $A\cap W_x$ of the $m$-sphere $S^m$, for $m\leq n$,
i.e. there is a commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^m @>{}>> A'\cap V_x\\
@VVV @VVV \\
B^{m+1} @>{}>> A\cap W_x
\end{CD}$$
By Theorem (1.28) a normal space has Lebesgue dimension $\leq n$ iff for each closed subset $A$ of $X$
it holds
$$ A\xrightarrow{i} B \perp S^n\rightarrow \{pt\}$$

Note that this theorem implies that each map in $\{S^n\to\{pt\}\}^{\perp lr}$ is $n$-soft,
and Theorem (5.22)(a) suggests a question whether a map of nice spaces is  $n$-soft iff it is in
$\{S^n\to\{pt\}\}^{\perp lr}$.